# problem pthread_mutex_lock wait forever if it is inside for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pthreads, mutex

I have a function as below it gets two pointers, a queue, and a command, and puts command inside the queue. since the queue is a shared resource between two threads I use a mutex.

```
int addtoQueue(Command_t* cmd,MyQueue_t* myQ){
    MyQueue_t *mq = myQ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mq->mu_queue);
    if(isFull(mq))
        return -1;
    insert(mq, cmd);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mq->mu_queue);
    pthread_cond_signal(&mq->cond);
    return mq->itemCount;
}
```

I write a test procedure in Google test as below.

```
TEST(QueueTest, AddOneElementToQueue) {
    MyQueue_t myQ;
    Command_t cmd;
    myQ.rear=0;
    myQ.front=0;
    myQ.itemCount=0;
    cmd.id=1;
    EXPECT_EQ(1, addtoQueue(&cmd, &myQ));
}


TEST(QueueTest, AddTenElementsToQueue) {
    MyQueue_t myQ;
    Command_t cmd[10];
    myQ.rear=0;
    myQ.front=0;
    myQ.itemCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        cmd[i].id=i;
        addtoQueue(&cmd[i], &myQ);
    }

    EXPECT_EQ(10, addtoQueue(&cmd[9], &myQ));
}
```

the result is very weird the first test that I put one command inside the queue worked successfully but the second stuck in

> pthread_mutex_lock(&mq->mu_queue)

line inside *addtoQueue* function.I found out that if I call this function inside for loop It stucks. what is the problem?

Comment: If `isFull` returns true, then `addtoQueue` doesn't unlock the mutex.

Comment: @ScottHunter it never reaches to isFull even for the first element and as you see I just created queue locally

Comment: Please don't edit your _original_ code to add code proposed by answers you get. This makes these answers non-sensical (e.g. when you edited your code block, it made _dreamcrash's_ answer non-sensical because it made it appear that he was proposing a change that didn't need to be done). The proper way to do this is to _append_ the updated code to your question, but leave the original intact. Or, if the issue is resolved, you may post your own _answer_ with the fulling working code.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah, I thought It may distract answers to something that is not the reason

Comment: when threads stuck in mutexes it is usefull to use broadcast !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I forgot to init mutex and cond

```
TEST(QueueTest, AddTenElementsToQueue) {
    MyQueue_t myQ;
    Command_t cmd[10];
    pthread_mutex_init(&myQ->mu_queue, NULL);<-----here
    pthread_cond_init(&myQ->cond, NULL);<-------here
    myQ.rear=0;
    myQ.front=0;
    myQ.itemCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        cmd[i].id=i;
        addtoQueue(&cmd[i], &myQ);
    }

    EXPECT_EQ(10, addtoQueue(&cmd[9], &myQ));
}
```

adding these two lines solved the problem All tests passed